# How can I delete tiff tags using the LibTiff.Net 2.3 library

Tags: c#, tags, tiff, libtiff.net

I can't seem to find any documentation of how to delete a tiff tag using the LibTiff.Net library.  I love the library but this one method is important to what I need to do.  At one point I was hoping that I could just set a tag and set it's value to nothing.  I had hoped that would work but that was a negative.

Anyone know how to delete a tiff tag using the LibTiff.Net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: As first this might look like a big answer but I wanted to make sure that whoever was looking at this see's all the "proprietary classes I have created to keep everything boxed up for cleanness.  In the interest of keeping the answer as sort as possible and to be informative I will only paste the code for the DeleteTiffTags method.  The rest of the code can be downloaded via [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=sVcTjdKQ).

Now on to the good stuff...  I ended up spending about a day on making this happen and it was possible thanks to various questions being answered by the great stackoverflow community.  I wrote two little (very detailed) method in one of my classes to delete a tiff tag.  The first one is meant to delete a list of given tags and the second one is to delete a single tag which works off the for mentioned method.  Also in this example I added a few lines to support my custom tiff tags...  They will all be preceded with the //ADDED comment.

Classes:

> public static class TIFFTAGS
>    - This class is the main class that is simply called by doing something like TIFFTAGS.DeleteTiffTags();  Since it's a static class
>   there is no need to create an object of it to use it's methods.
>
> private class TIFFTAGS_PAGE
>    - This class is a private class that resides inside the TIFFTAGS class.  It's purpose is to contain all the single page info for all
>   the pages that might be in the tiff.  It is private and only used for
>   internal purposes.
>
> public class TIFFTAGS_TAG
>    - This is a class I made to wrap up the tags in something more to my liking.  Using the standard tag type names such as ASCII, SHORT, LONG,
>   and RATIONAL.

Methods/Functions:

> TagExtender()
>    - This little gem is a callback function that allows you to actually keep your CUSTOM tags in the tiff.  Without it ALL of your custom tags
>   would disappear when you deleted any tag (even if you deleted just
>   one).
>
> DeleteTiffTags()
>    - This is the main method that deletes a list of tags.  Simply pass in a list of ushort tag numbers and all will be deleted.  Keep in mind
>   not using the TagExtender function will cause your custom tags to go
>   *poof*!
>
> DeleteTiffTag()
>    - This is simply used to delete a single tiff tag.  It calls upon DeleteTiffTags() to handle the grunt work.

```
public static bool DeleteTiffTags(string sFileName, List<ushort> ushortTagNumbers)
{
    //Deletes a list of tiff tag from the given image
    //Returns true if successful or false if error occured
     //Define variables
    List<TIFFTAGS_PAGE> ttPage = new List<TIFFTAGS_PAGE>();
     //Check for empty list
    if (ushortTagNumbers.Count == 0) return false;
     try
    {
        //ADDED
        m_lTagsToWrite = new List<TIFFTAGS_TAG>();
        m_lTagsToWrite.Add(new TIFFTAGS_TAG("", 38001, Convert.ToString("")));
        m_lTagsToWrite.Add(new TIFFTAGS_TAG("", 38002, Convert.ToString("")));
        m_parentExtender = Tiff.SetTagExtender(TagExtender);
         //Open the file for reading
        using (Tiff input = Tiff.Open(sFileName, "r"))
        {
            if (input == null) return false;
             //Get page count
            int numberOfDirectories = input.NumberOfDirectories();
             //Go through all the pages
            for (short i = 0; i < numberOfDirectories; ++i)
            {
                //Set the page
                input.SetDirectory(i);
                 //Create a new tags dictionary to store all my tags
                Dictionary<ushort, FieldValue[]> dTags = new Dictionary<ushort, FieldValue[]>();
                 //Get all the tags for the page
                for (ushort t = ushort.MinValue; t < ushort.MaxValue; ++t)
                {
                    TiffTag tag = (TiffTag)t;
                    FieldValue[] tagValue = input.GetField(tag);
                    if (tagValue != null)
                    {
                        dTags.Add(t, tagValue);
                    }
                }
                 //Check if the page is encoded
                bool encoded = false;
                FieldValue[] compressionTagValue = input.GetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION);
                if (compressionTagValue != null)
                    encoded = (compressionTagValue[0].ToInt() != (int)Compression.NONE);

                //Create a new byte array to store all my image data
                int numberOfStrips = input.NumberOfStrips();
                byte[] byteImageData = new byte[numberOfStrips * input.StripSize()];
                int offset = 0;
                 //Get all the image data for the page
                for (int n = 0; n < numberOfStrips; ++n)
                {
                    int bytesRead;
                    if (encoded)
                        bytesRead = input.ReadEncodedStrip(n, byteImageData, offset, byteImageData.Length - offset);
                    else
                        bytesRead = input.ReadRawStrip(n, byteImageData, offset, byteImageData.Length - offset);
                     //Add to the offset keeping up with where we are
                    offset += bytesRead;
                }
                 //Save all the tags, image data, and height, etc for the page
                TIFFTAGS_PAGE tiffPage = new TIFFTAGS_PAGE();
                tiffPage.Height = input.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
                tiffPage.Tags = dTags;
                tiffPage.PageData = byteImageData;
                tiffPage.Encoded = encoded;
                tiffPage.StripSize = input.StripSize();
                tiffPage.StripOffset = input.GetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS)[0].ToIntArray()[0];
                ttPage.Add(tiffPage);
            }
        }
         //Open the file for writing
        using (Tiff output = Tiff.Open(sFileName + "-new.tif", "w"))
        {
            if (output == null) return false;
             //Go through all the pages
            for (short i = 0; i < ttPage.Count(); ++i)
            {
                //Write all the tags for the page
                foreach (KeyValuePair<ushort, FieldValue[]> tagValue in ttPage[i].Tags)
                {
                    //Write all the tags except the one's needing to be deleted
                    if (!ushortTagNumbers.Contains(tagValue.Key))
                    {
                        TiffTag tag = (TiffTag)tagValue.Key;
                        output.GetTagMethods().SetField(output, tag, tagValue.Value);
                    }
                }
                 //Set the height for the page
                output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, ttPage[i].Height);
                 //Set the offset for the page
                output.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS, ttPage[i].StripOffset);
                 //Save page data along with tags
                output.CheckpointDirectory();
                 //Write each strip one at a time using the same orginal strip size
                int numberOfStrips = ttPage[i].PageData.Length / ttPage[i].StripSize;
                int offset = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < numberOfStrips; ++n)
                {
                    //Write all the image data (strips) for the page
                    if (ttPage[i].Encoded)
                        //output.WriteEncodedStrip(n, byteStrip, offset, byteStrip.Length - offset);
                        output.WriteEncodedStrip(0, ttPage[i].PageData, offset, ttPage[i].StripSize - offset);
                    else
                        output.WriteRawStrip(n, ttPage[i].PageData, offset, ttPage[i].StripSize - offset);
                     //Add to the offset keeping up with where we are
                    offset += ttPage[i].StripOffset;
                }
                 //Save the image page
                output.WriteDirectory();
            }
        }
         //ADDED
        Tiff.SetTagExtender(m_parentExtender);
    }
    catch
    {
        //ADDED
        Tiff.SetTagExtender(m_parentExtender);

        //Error occured
        return false;
    }
     //Return success
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look at TiffCP utility (and especially its source code) shipped with LibTiff.Net.

LibTiff.Net doesn't offer methods for removing tags (the same is true for LibTiff). You will need to implement *part* of TiffCP functionality in order to achieve that.

Basically, you will need to copy all tags you wish to retain, and copy pixels data *without decoding and re-encoding* it.

Please also have a look at [Convert a multi-strip TIFF image to a single-strip one](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/ConvertToSingleStrip) sample. It shows how to copy tags and copy raw (undecoded data) from one image to another. The sample actually decodes data in some cases because it needs to change number of strips, but you won't need to decode data.

Comment: Wow!  This looks like exactly what I'm after.  I would much rather deal with the exposed methods then digging into the private ones.  Thanks a bunch for pointing that out Bobrovsky!  And I just got the "vote up" privilege too...  Guess where I'll be using my first vote?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to basically copy the input file to a new TIFF image filtering out the tags you don't want in the process.  Take a look at the tiffcp utility which is part of the regular libtiff distribution.  It sort of does that, minus filtering.

Disclaimer:  I've never used LibTiff.Net and am assuming that it is very similar to the LibTiff.

Take a look at tiffcp.c

First it manually copies/sets some known tags such as resolution, compression, colors etc.
Then it copies all a set of tags that can be copied w/o preprocessing:

```
for (p = tags; p < &tags[NTAGS]; p++)
    CopyTag(p->tag, p->count, p->type);
```

Then it copies the actual pixel data.  This will from what I recollect, drop any tags that are not known to tiffcp.  If your tag that you want to drop is in the list, you can trivially drop it by removing it from that list.

Comment: The "filtering" part is the key.  I'm not sure how I would do that.  Looked at tiffcp.exe and it just seems to simply copy the tiff with a different type of compression etc..

Comment: You should be looking at the source code, not the exe?  I've updated the answer above with some details.

Comment: Thanks MK, I'm looking into the c# code now.  Found the area that is similar to the one you posted in c.  Time to dig into it.  ;)